# Get information from multiple web services using single data type of data object

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, ofx

I have a helper class,

```
    public class Bill
    {
        public string BillId {get; set;}
        public double Amount {get; set;}
        public DateTime DueDate {get; set;}
    }
```

**WebService1** : Reference to Bill

```
    [WebMethod]
    public Bill GetBill(string accountId)
    {
        /* Create and return the bill object */
    }
```

**WebService2** : Reference to Bill

```
    [WebMethod]
    public Bill GetBill(string accountId)
    {
        /* Create and return the bill object */
    }
```

**Client Application** : Reference to Bill, WebService1, WebService2

```
    public void GetBillInformaton
    {
        /* Looping through all the bill requests from a user */
        List<Bill> bills = new List<Bill>();
        foreach (BillRequest)
            if (BillRequest.ServiceProvider = Service1)
                bills.Add(WebService1.GetBill(BillRequest.AccountId)
            else if (BillRequest.ServiceProvider = Service2)
                bills.Add(WebService2.GetBill(BillRequest.AccountId)
            ....
            ....
    }
```

If I want two web services (initially later on may more) to return me their contract information in the form of above class object and use it in one client application referring to both web services,

**Q1** Is it possible what I am trying to do here?
**Q2** If not, a better way of doing it please.

**Additional Info**
For a scenario what I am trying to do here is to implement a prototype standard protocol among billers so a client application can aggregate information using common data object.

Comment: ASMX web services are a legacy technology which should not be used for new development. One of the reasons is that they can't do what you want. Use WCF instead, which can.

Comment: Thank you for directing me to the right path... was so helpful.